# Validate all the inputs of a table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, loops

I have a set of inputs that are dynamically generated and their id's incremented based on the number of items in an array

```
                    <table width="100%">

                      <?php $i = 1; ?>
                          <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><b><?php echo $product['name']; ?></b></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="firstname_<?php echo $i; ?>">First Name:</label>
                                    <input name="firstname_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="firstname_<?php echo $i; ?>" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="lastname_<?php echo $i; ?>">Last Name:</label>
                                    <input name="lastname_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="lastname_<?php echo $i; ?>" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="recipient_number_<?php echo $i; ?>"> Phone Number:</label>
                                    <input name="recipient_number_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="recipient_number_<?php echo $i; ?>" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="recipient_email_<?php echo $i; ?>"> Email:</label>
                                    <input name="recipient_number_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="recipient_email_<?php echo $i; ?>" required>
                                </div>                                  
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <?php $i++; ?>
                      <?php } ?>

                </table>
```

I am trying to look for a way using JQuery to loop through all the generated inputs to ensure they are not empty

Comment: `$("input[type=text]")` will give you all the input boxes present in document.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I needed it to be the inputs specifically generated in the table not all the inputs in the document

Comment: then modify the html like `<table class="table_with_input" width="100%">` and then you can select all the inputs under it as `$("table.table_with_input").find("input[type=text]")`

Comment: Check my answer   http://stackoverflow.com/a/39485393/6608101

Answer (score 0):

try using this -
 you can replace `table` with a table Id here  - `$('#tableId :input')`

```
$('table :input').each(function(){
    //Enter your code to validate input
    console.log($(this).attr('name') + " : " + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Hi, it loops through the inputs but it loops through each set of generated inputs based on the number of input fields (firstname, lastname, recipient_number, email will be looped through four times if there is 1 item in the array, 8 times if there are two, etc)

Comment: In your question you mentioned that `I am trying to look for a way using JQuery to loop through all the generated inputs to ensure they are not empty` - So it means that you want to loop all the inputs present within the table..? you did not specify that 1 item contains four inputs and you want to loop through the number of items present! or how would you expect to check that if all the input values are not empty if you are  only going loop a single Input in each item ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

This will allow you to validate the fields which are empty, and try to use the filter, that helps you to do it without any loop.

More information [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
$('#sender_container').on('submit',function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   validate();
});
function validate()
{
  $('#sender_container > input[type="text"]')
      .removeClass('error')
      .filter(function()       { 
        // Remove error classes. Filter
        return !$.trim(this.value);
      })
      .addClass('error');
}
```

```css
.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="sender_container">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```